# Creating a custom loss function in tensorflow using intermediate layer output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a self distillation based model.
The code of the model is as follows :

```py
def create_cnn_model(input_shape, num_classes,y_true):
    model = Sequential()

    # first
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    
    # Intermediate layer
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='intermediate_layer',padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    # Deep layer
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='deep_layer',padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    # Flatten for the final layers
    model.add(Flatten())

    # Final classification layers
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='final_classification'))
    return model
```

I'm using an additional cnn model as classifier, code is as follows:

```py
def classifier(name,model):
    classification_model = models.Sequential()
    classification_model.add(layers.Input(shape=model.get_layer(name).output_shape[1:]))  
    classification_model.add(layers.Flatten())
    classification_model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    classification_model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='classification_output'))
    classification_output = classification_model.get_layer('classification_output').output
    return classification_output
```

My custom loss function makes use of output from intermediate layer, code is as follows :

```py
def custom_loss(model):
    # function that accepts the ground truth and predictions
    def sd_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        intermediate_output=classifier('intermediate_layer',model)
        feature_loss=l2_feature_loss(model.get_layer('intermediate_layer').output, model.get_layer('deep_layer').output)
        kl_loss=tf.keras.losses.kullback_leibler_divergence(intermediate_output, y_pred)
        cross_entropy_loss1=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, intermediate_output)
        cross_entropy_loss2=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        ce_loss=cross_entropy_loss1+cross_entropy_loss2
        total_loss=feature_loss+kl_loss+ce_loss
        return total_loss
    # return the inner function tuned by the hyperparameter
    return sd_loss
```

However I am getting the following error :

TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_7'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.